# Error creating store view - An error occurred while saving. Please review the error log

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error, store-view

Hi I am getting this error for no apparent reason and I see nothing in my system.log which is related to this.

I also cannot find any other similar questions that relate to an error creating store views specifically and so am stuck on what I can try!

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Please be more specific. what does your current setup of stores look like? what variables are used to define them? Is the input your trying to save legit? There are too many possible causes to get to 1 answer.

Comment: `exception.log` would be the place to look. If logging is not disabled via configuration.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This was a conflict with a FAQ plugin, disabling the plugin allows me to create a store.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.0 and earlier have this error if used with PHP >=5.5

#### If this is your setup, you have two options:

- Update to Magento 1.9.1.1
- Downgrade PHP to 5.4

I would not recommend downgrading PHP for security reasons, that leaves you with upgrading Magento. Since Magento 1.9.2 still hase some bugs, your safest bet is 1.9.1.1 +SUPEE-5995 +SUPEE-6285

***Edit:*** The 3rd option is to patch `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php` to make it PHP 5.5 compatible, as described here:
[PHP 5.5 Bug - Deprecated functionality: preg_replace()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39903/php-5-5-bug-deprecated-functionality-preg-replace)